# Show that a quarter-circle always contains a point $(x,y)$ with rational $x$ and irrational $y$

Tags: analytic-geometry, circles, irrational-numbers, rational-numbers

> Let $r\in\mathbb{R}^{+}.$ Let $\mathbb{D}_r=(0,r)\cap\mathbb{Q}.$ That is, $\mathbb{D}_r$ is the set of all rationals strictly greater than $0,$ and strictly less than $r.$ Let $f_r:\mathbb{D}_r\to\mathbb{R}$ be a function given by $f_r(x)=\sqrt{r^2-x^2}.$ Show that the range of $f$ contains atleast one irrational number.

Case $1:$

Let $r\in\mathbb{Q}.$ Then, $\frac{r}{2}\in\mathbb{Q},$ and since $0<\frac{r}{2}<r,$ we have that $\frac{r}{2}\in\mathbb{D}_r.$ Moreover, $f_r\left(\frac{r}{2}\right)=\frac{r\sqrt{3}}{2}.$ This must be irrational as $\sqrt{3}$ is irrational.

Case $2:$

Let $r\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q},$ and let $r^2\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$ as well. Let $a\in\mathbb{D}_r.$ Then, $f_r(a)^2+a^2=r^2.$ Let $f_r(a)$ be rational. Then, $r^2,$ as a sum of two rational is also rational. This contradicts the irrationality of $r^2.$ Hence, $f_r(a)$ must be irrational.

Case $3:$

This is the case where $r$ is irrational but $r^2$ is rational. How to deal with this case?

Comment: Could you clarifies what this definition of D means?

Comment: @AnneAunyme, yes, $\mathbb{D}$ is the set of all rationals larger than $0$ and less than $r.$

Comment: So you mean [0,r] rather than (0,r), right?

Comment: [0, r] includes 0 and r in the interval, when D is the set of all rationals between 0 and r (which does not include 0  and r)

Comment: @Hayst I don't understand... where do you get that D doesn't include 0 nor r? AFAIK the notation "(0,r)" means "a pair of 0 and r" and that's not a set. Then OP suggested it was "the set of the numbers larger than 0 and lesser than r" (aka [0,r], as "larger than" usually means "larger or equal" not "strictly larger"). And now what you say suggests it means ]0,r[, although you didn't say it explicitly and it doesn't match with op's explanation...

Comment: @AnneAunyme The notation $(a,b)$ sometimes means a pair, but in the context of sets it means the set of numbers (usually real numbers) greater than $a$ and less than $b$, that is, $\{x\in\mathbb R : a < x < b\}$. This is standard notation in many textbooks. Yes, some people write $]a,b[$ instead, but it's far from universal. And "larger than" means "strictly larger than" in most texts. There may be exceptions, but on MSE it's much safer to assume "strictly larger than".

Comment: Is not it sufficient to take any rational number from $\mathbb D$ and apply method of "Case 1"?

Comment: @user, I don't see how that would work. Take the case where $r=\sqrt{5}.$ Then, $f_{r}(x)=\sqrt{5-x^2}.$ Take $x=2$ to get $f_{r}(2)=1,$ which is rational. So, we can't just arbitrarily take some $q\in\mathbb{D}$ and say that $f_r(q)$ must be irrational like what we did with Case $1.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose for a contradiction that all numbers in the range of $f$ are rational. Pick any $x\in\mathbb D_r$. Then $r^2-x^2$ is rational, so $r^2$ is rational too. Then there exist natural $p$ and $q$ such that $r^2=\tfrac pq$.
Then $\frac 1{2q}\in\mathbb D_r$. Thus $r^2-\left(\frac 1{2q}\right)^2$ is a square of a rational number. Then $4pq-1$
is a square of a natural number, that is impossible because  each square of a natural number is $0$ or $1$ modulo $4$.

Answer (score 1):

This answer deals with case 3 where $r$ is irrational but $r^2$ is rational $\frac qp$ where $p,q$ are positive integers satisfying $\gcd(p,q)=1$.

- If $q$ is odd, then taking an even integer $a$ larger than $r$, we get $$f_r\bigg(\frac{r^2}{a}\bigg)=\sqrt{\frac qp--\frac{q^2}{a^2p^2}}=\frac{1}{ap}\sqrt{a^2pq-q^2}$$ which is irrational since $a^2pq-q^2\equiv 3\pmod 4$.
- If $q$ is even of the form $2^st$ where $s,t$ are positive integers with $t\equiv 1\pmod 2$, then taking $a$ of the form $2^{s+1}u$ larger than $r$ where $u\equiv 1\pmod 2$, we get $$\begin{align}f_r\bigg(\frac{r^2}{a}\bigg)&=\sqrt{\frac{a^2pq-q^2}{a^2p^2}}
  \\\\&=\sqrt{\frac{2^{2s+2}u^2p\cdot 2^st-2^{2s}t^2}{2^{2s+2}u^2p^2}}
  \\\\&=\sqrt{\frac{2^{s+2}u^2pt-t^2}{4u^2p^2}}\\\\&=\frac{1}{2up}\sqrt{2^{s+2}u^2pt-t^2}\end{align}$$ which is irrational since $2^{s+2}u^2pt-t^2\equiv 3\pmod 4$.